# Is there a way to quickly validate data using Perl and XML::Simple

Tags: xml, perl, xml-parsing

My XML file looks like this:

```
<A>
 <file>data1</file>
 <path>data2</path>
</A>

<B>
  <file>data3</file>
  <path>data4</path>
</B>
```

So I read the data from a log file, parse it and get tags like `A`, `B`, `file` and `path`. Right now I use a for loop to iterate over each outer tag, and then compare against each sub tag to see if the data exists in the XML file.

```
$data = $xml->XMLin("xmlfile");

foreach $e ( $data->{$outerTag} ) # outertag could be A, B
{
 if( $e->{file} eq $fname ) { do_something } else { return 0; }
 if( $e->{path} eq $pname ) { do_something } else { return 0; }
}
```

Is there a way whereby I don't have to use the `for` loop.? Say I could do something like this (I am making this up):

```
if( $data->{$outerTag}->{$fname} ) { do_something } else { return 0; }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As long as `XML::Simple` has built a rational structure for your data you can write

```
if ( $data->{$outerTag}{file} eq $fname ) { ... }
```

but, depending on what you want to do with the data, you may well be better off using a better XML parser, like `XML::LibXML`.

Comment: No. That is why other XML parsers are preferable. It is possible to use the `ForceArray` option to make it so that there is *always* an array even if it contains just one element, but that is a bit clunky IMO. Explain what you actually want to do and we will help.

Comment: it is for a tool i am building. Basically someone will run it once a week, and the log file that i read data from gets updated with new but sometimes it has old stuff. My tool will basically waive anything that is old and only log new data. Waive as in ignore old data. Hope it is clear :)

Comment: So where does the XML come from? Can you edit your question to show a sample please?

Comment: the sample is in the question (xml part). :)

Answer (score 2):

Perl doesn't have an official "XML parser"; there are a plethora of [options to choose from](https://metacpan.org/search?q=xml+parser+libxml), some better than others depending on the application.

You may want to read up about [XML validation using schemas](http://www.w3schools.com/schema/default.asp). In a nutshell, you need to write up a schema for what you deem as valid XML, then validate the XML file against it.

Answer (score 1):

Most of the standards based XML schema validators are Java or Python based nowadays :-(

I would suggest using xmllint and you could also look at [XMLLint perl module](http://cpan.uwinnipeg.ca/htdocs/Meta/Meta/Tool/Xmllint.pm.html).

## Example

```
$ xmllint --noout --schema schema.xml data.xml
data.xml validates
```

### data.xml

```
<data>
  <A>
    <file>data1</file>
    <path>data2</path>
  </A>
  <B>
    <file>data3</file>
    <path>data4</path>
  </B>
</data>
```

### schema.xml

```
<xsd:schema xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" attributeFormDefault="unqualified" elementFormDefault="qualified" version="1.0">
  <xsd:element name="data" type="dataType"/>
  <xsd:complexType name="dataType">
    <xsd:sequence>
      <xsd:element name="A" type="AType"/>
      <xsd:element name="B" type="BType"/>
    </xsd:sequence>
  </xsd:complexType>
  <xsd:complexType name="BType">
    <xsd:sequence>
      <xsd:element name="file" type="xsd:string"/>
      <xsd:element name="path" type="xsd:string"/>
    </xsd:sequence>
  </xsd:complexType>
  <xsd:complexType name="AType">
    <xsd:sequence>
      <xsd:element name="file" type="xsd:string"/>
      <xsd:element name="path" type="xsd:string"/>
    </xsd:sequence>
  </xsd:complexType>
</xsd:schema>
```

**Note:**

- Used [this website](http://www.xmlforasp.net/codebank/system_xml_schema/buildschema/buildxmlschema.aspx) to generate the schema file.